# Replicating TextField behaviour of material.io

Tags: reactjs, material-design

material.io has a demo of a TextField that contains a starting adornment with a large label.  When you click inside the box, the label animates to the top of the TextField (see https://material.io/components/text-fields for demo.  Outlined Leading Icon)

[image]

[image]

How can I replicate this animation in Material UI? This code shows the leading icon and the end result https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kskiw?file=/demo.js but as you can see no animation takes place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/ InputAdornment section

Comment: Thanks - I have edited my question to make it clear I am already using the InputAdornment, but that's not really the issue, it's the animation alongside the icon that I am struggling with.

Comment: there is password field which next to amount field has same animation as you expect

Comment: Yes I also tried to switch the adornment on that code, but then the animation stops! Try it!